# Optimizing CUDA FDTD Fortran

Tags: cuda, fortran

I am trying to optimize this FDTD code with CUDA Fortran. I have three 3-D cube matrix with input, output and costant.

```
attributes (global) subroutine kernel_h(k,num_cells_x,num_cells_y,num_cells_z,Hx,Hy,Hz,Ex,Ey,Ez,Cbdx,Cbdy,Cbdz)
    implicit none
    integer :: idx,idy
    integer,value :: k,num_cells_x,num_cells_y,num_cells_z
    real(kind=8), intent(in), dimension(1:num_cells_x,1:num_cells_y,1:num_cells_z) :: Ex, Ey, Ez
    real(kind=8), intent(inout), dimension(1:num_cells_x,1:num_cells_y,1:num_cells_z) :: Hx, Hy, Hz
    real(kind=8), intent(in), constant, dimension(1:num_cells_x,1:num_cells_y,1:num_cells_z) :: Cbdx,Cbdy,Cbdz
    idx = threadIdx%x + ((blockIdx%x-1) * blockDim%x)
    idy = threadIdx%y + ((blockIdx%y-1) * blockDim%y)
    do while (idx < num_cells_x)
        Hz(idx,idy,k) = Hz(idx,idy,k) + ((Ex(idx,idy+1,k)-Ex(idx,idy,k))*Cbdy(idx,idy,k) + (Ey(idx,idy,k)-Ey(idx+1,idy,k))*Cbdx(idx,idy,k))
        Hx(idx,idy,k) = Hx(idx,idy,k) + ((Ey(idx,idy,k+1)-Ey(idx,idy,k))*Cbdz(idx,idy,k) + (Ez(idx,idy,k)-Ez(idx,idy+1,k))*Cbdy(idx,idy,k))
        Hy(idx,idy,k) = Hy(idx,idy,k) + ((Ez(idx+1,idy,k)-Ez(idx,idy,k))*Cbdx(idx,idy,k) + (Ex(idx,idy,k)-Ex(idx,idy,k+1))*Cbdz(idx,idy,k))
        idx = idx + (blockDim%x * gridDim%x)
        idy = idy + (blockDim%y * gridDim%y)
    end do
end subroutine kernel_h
```

and my kernel launch is:

```
bdim=dim3(16,16,1)
gdim=dim3((num_cells_x+(bdim%x-1))/bdim%x,(num_cells_y+(bdim%y-1))/bdim%y,1)
do k=1,num_cells_z
 call kernel_h<<<gdim,bdim>>>(k,num_cells_x,num_cells_y,num_cells_z,Hx_d,Hy_d,Hz_d,Ex_d,Ey_d,Ez_d,Cbdx_d,Cbdy_d,Cbdz_d)
end do
```

My questions are: why i can't load more than 100x100x100 matrix? If i try i get a kernel error launch failure. And can i improve my code performace? I think it could be written in a better way.

Comment: How much VGA memory do you have?

Comment: Device name: GeForce GTX 295
    Execution Configuration Limits
      Maximum Grid Dimensions: 65535 x 65535 x 1
      Maximum Block Dimensions: 512 x 512 x 64
      Maximum Threads per Block: 512

    Off-Chip Memory
      Total Global Memory (B): 938803200
      Total Constant Memory (B): 65536
      Maximum Memory Pitch for Copies (B): 2147483647
      Integrated: No

    On-Chip Memory
      Shared Memory per Multiprocessor (B): 16384
      Number of Registers per Multiprocessor: 16384

Comment: That should be enough for that array. Anyway, CUDA Fortran is a proprietary format of PGI, so you should seek support from them. Some support contract is probably part of your license.

Comment: Is this running on your main display GPU?  Is the kernel running for multiple seconds?  What OS are you running on? My guess is you are getting a TDR.

Comment: Hello. My running execution time is 16.62646 ms. The GPU is the main GPU.
My system is: Linux 2.6.32-39-server #86-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 13 23:15:11 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
What is TDR?
Do you think can i unroll the loop inside the kernel?

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that you are accessing out of bounds.

Consider a 10x10x10 volume (x,y,z). In that case you will launch a single block of 16x16 threads. These threads will access a 17x17 slice (since stencil radius is 1) which is clearly going to end up out of bounds. You would need to disable those threads that will access out of bounds and also disable those threads that will reach beyond the boundary to apply their stencil.

Consider looking at the FDTD3D sample in the CUDA SDK. Granted it's in C but it illustrates how to handle this problem and it also shows how to use shared memory to have a **much** more efficient implementation.

Comment: The usage of `k` is OK - it is passed by value from the host side loop.

Comment: Thanks talonmies, I missed that. Edited my answer accordingly.